# Can we post links to liveatc?

Tags: discussion

I answered a [question regarding military intercepts recently](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1696/whats-the-point-of-intercepting-an-aircraft). A few days later someone posted a recording of an interception of a Bonanza in a TFR (VIP movement) in the [forums at liveatc.net](http://www.liveatc.net/forums/atcaviation-audio-clips/potus-tfr-violation-%28palm-springs%29/). Very interesting too, with both UHF and VHF (Guard) communication. Can I link to it in the question? The problems I see is that a) you need to register to download the clip, and b) I don't like linking to forums as I suppose you never know how long the thread will survive, but maybe that's just me.

Also, assuming I have permission to distribute the clip, is it possible to store it on stackexchange somehow, like with images?

Comment: Well, you can post links to about anywhere, but you may want to include a disclaimer that registration is required (especially since that site doesn't make it obvious that you need to register in order to see the attachments).  Otherwise you may annoy some people.  :)  I don't know of anyway to upload it to SE though so you could only find some other place to store and link it.

Comment: You can upload it to youtube and embed it in your answer (if you can upload audio to youtube). We at gaming see youtube clips in answers a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any problem with linking to LiveATC ([or the YouTube trick One-One mentioned](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/users/82/one-one), particularly if you want to add helpful illustrations & annotations).

Leaving a "(Registration required)" note would be nice, but I think most aviation enthusiasts won't mind registering for access to the LiveATC archives.

Comment: This seems like a pretty reasonable solution. I tend to do similar disclaimers for big .pdf files, or other things that have some barrier to entry, so it makes sense in this context.

Comment: I link people to NTSB report PDFs - I have no shame! :-)